# Mongo converts Set to List

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a variable 
`Map<String,Object> parameters;`  in a class. When saved and loaded from mongo, if this Object is of type `Set`, it is converted to `List`. How to retain it as `Set`?

Edit:

Adding more context

```
public class Param{
        Map<String,Object> parameters;

        public Param(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
            this.parameters = parameters;
        }

        public Map<String, Object> getParameters() {
            return parameters;
        }

        public void setParameters(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
            this.parameters = parameters;
        }
    }
```

Saving as below

```
Set<String> obj = new HashSet<>();
        obj.add("ab");
        obj.add("cd");
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("12",obj);
    Param param = new Param(parameters);
    MongoTemplate mongotemplate = ....
    mongotemplate.insert(param);
```

while reading

```
 MongoTemplate mongotemplate = ....
   Query query = ...
   Param mongoparam = mongotemplate
                .find(query, Param.class).get(0);
   Set<String> obj = (Set) mongoparam.get("12")
```

last line is throwing error that Arraylist cannot be cast to Set

Comment: Im pretty sure that mongo only accepts standard data types

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: i mean that it only stores/accepts standard data types, so numbers, strings, booleans, arrays, objects

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more code or explanation. I'd have to guess how you use your object from the context of the question. E.g. how does   the conversion take place?

Comment: @getjackx added more information

Comment: Take a look in [the API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#find-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-java.lang.Class-) . find() returns List<Param> So when you call `monogoparam.get("12")` it should return a Param object. The Set is encapsulated by `monogoparam.get(MYPARAMID).getParameters().get("12")` This is at least what i'd expect from the API reference and your code. The exception is that mongoparam - the List - cannot be casted to Set.

Comment: @getjackx  This is just a sample code . I have updated it now .. Assume I got param safely as shown in edit

Comment: `Set<String> obj = new HashSet<String>(mongoparam.get("12"))` try this.